# Upper bound of the sum of probabilities

Tags: probability, summation, upper-lower-bounds

Let $X$ be a discrete random variable, such that $X\in \{1,\ldots, k\}$. Let $P(X=i)=p_i$, for $i=1,\ldots, k$ and $p_1+\ldots p_k=1$. I want to find an upper bound for the following expression
$$
\sum_{j=1}^{k}\sum_{m\neq j}p_{j}(1-p_j)p_{m} + \sum_{j=1}^{k}\sum_{m\neq j}p_{j}(1-p_m)p_{m} + \sum_{j=1}^{k}\sum_{m\neq j}p_{j}p_{m}(1-p_j-p_m) = \sum_{j=1}^{k}\sum_{m\neq j}p_{j}p_{m}(3-2p_j-2p_m).
$$
I want to show that it can be bounded above by approximately $\frac{3k}{4}$. Several numerical simulations show that this bound is likely to hold, but I can't show it analytically. I tried to bound $p_m$ between $0$ and $1$, but it turns out that the bound is too loose. Can anyone provide some insights to whether this bound is achievable or not? Thanks!

Comment: Possibly helpful inequality is $p(1-p)\le1/4$ for $p\in[0,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $p_1,...,p_k$ be nonnegative real numbers such that $p_1+\cdots +p_k$=1.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&
\sum_{j=1}^k\sum_{m\ne j}p_jp_m(3-2p_j-2p_m)
\\[4pt]
\le\;&
\sum_{j=1}^k\sum_{m\ne j}3p_jp_m
\\[4pt]
=\;&
3\sum_{j=1}^kp_j\sum_{m\ne j}p_m
\\[4pt]
=\;&
3\sum_{j=1}^kp_j(1-p_j)
\\[4pt]
\le\;&
3\sum_{j=1}^k\frac{1}{4}
\\[4pt]
=\;&
\frac{3k}{4}
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}